# Complicated tag consolidations

Tags: discussion, tagging

This post is for tag groups which should probably be consolidated but are more complicated and/or involve more than two tags.

Vote up if you think the group *should* be merged.  Vote down if you the the group *should not* be merged.

*Please* comment to explain your reasoning, detail an exception, or propose an alternate solution.

Comment: For those not aware there are tools in place for the community to propose and vote on tag synonyms: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/

Comment: Will these threads still be useful for discussion/keeping topics in a single place?

Answer (score 2):

accessories/equipment/attachment/gadget/kitchen-tools/utensils

Answer (score 1):

maintenance/cleaning/equipment-maintenance

Answer (score -1):

rotten/spoiled/food-preservation/storage-lifetime/storage-food

Comment: rotten/spoiled is not the same as food preservation. You can want to know how to store somehting with out needing to know the hallmarks of spoilage for that food.

Answer (score -1):

calories/health/nutrition/dieting/low-fat/low-sodium

Comment: At least three of those tags refer to off-topic subjects and shouldn't exist at all.

Comment: Right, but if one of them is okay, like the broader "health", then we could just consolidate the rest.

Answer (score -1):

classification/terminology/definition/grade/language

Comment: More meta-tags that shouldn't exist at all.  `[language]` might be OK, the rest should just be removed.

Comment: This thread is about consolidation, so if one of them is okay, then the question is whether the rest are appropriately overlapping to be merged.  I don't know what the 'master' term is, although I think there is a group of questions which all have to do with what things are properly or technically called.  The odd-man out might be [grade] which can probably be merged with [USDA] or renamed [meat-grade].

Answer (score -2):

chopping/cutting/paring/knife-skills/knives

Comment: I don't think `[knives]` necessarily implies `[knife-skills]`, or vice versa.  `[cutting]` is a non-specific term that should definitely be merged with `[knife-skills]`, while `[chopping]` are `[paring]` are more specific - I'm not entirely convinced that they need to go.

Comment: agreed with aaronut, although paring, slicing and chopping are types of knife skills, there are specifics in each one that would support their own tags.

Answer (score -2):

outdoor-cooking/camping/grilling?

Comment: Grilling is the odd one out. I can think of many grilling questions that do not apply to outdoor / camping cooking. There are also all sorts of outdoor / camping cooking subjects that do not involve grilling, e.g. anything involving cold salads.